# HTML5 picture element bug in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

[Here is result in Chrome which is right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN4FF.png)

[Here is result in IE which is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIsVW.png)

And here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style>
body, div, html
{
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 width: 100%;
}
form
{
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 max-width: 1280px;
 width: 100%;
}
img
{
 flex: none;
 max-width: 100%;
 min-height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
}
picture {width: 80%;}
#temp {background-color: red;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1">
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 600px)" srcset="../tmp.jpg">
  <source media="(max-width: 960px)" srcset="../tmp.jpg">  
  <img src="../tmp.jpg">                
</picture>        
<div id="temp">123123123123</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Why picture element in ie appear this blank while in chrome not?
IE version is IE 11 in windows 10,Chrome version is 57.0.2987.110.
What's wrong with IE?
And how can I delete the blank in IE?Thanks

Comment: Because IE doesn't support this element ? http://caniuse.com/#search=picture First support in MS is Edge 13

Comment: I tried some more times and found the problem seems to be the flexbox.If you don't use flexbox,it is already ok.Maybe flexbox and picture element makes some trouble.

Comment: The picture element in IE11 is unsupported. http://caniuse.com/#picture and renders as an inline element of HTMLUnknown. To correct the problem, just remove the picture{width:80%} rule... (picture elements are grouping elements, viz they group a collection of img elements)

Comment: Thanks for  Rob Parsons's reply.I tried removed the picture{width:80%} rule,it used.However I need to reduce the width to 80%.I tried set it's parent div widht to 80%,but the problem goes again.How can i set the width to 80%?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, may be it works in your browser.

```
<style type="text/css">
img {
        width:100%;
        max-width:100%;
        min-height:1px;
        -webkit-flex:none;
        -moz-flex:none;
        -ms-flex:none;
        -o-flex:none;
        flex:none;
    }
    form {
        max-width:1280px;
        width:100%;
        -webkit-display:flex;
        -moz-display:flex;
        -ms-display:flex;
        -o-display:flex;
        display:flex;
        -webkit-justify-content:center;
        -moz-justify-content:center;
        -ms-justify-content:center;
        -o-justify-content:center;
        justify-content:center;
        -webkit-align-items:center;
        -moz-align-items:center;
        -ms-align-items:center;
        -o-align-items:center;
        align-items:center;
        -webkit-flex-direction:column;
        -moz-flex-direction:column;
        -ms-flex-direction:column;
        -o-flex-direction:column;
        flex-direction:column;
    }
    html, body, div{
        width:100%;
        -webkit-display:flex;
        -moz-display:flex;
        -ms-display:flex;
        -o-display:flex;
        display:flex;
        -webkit-justify-content:center;
        -moz-justify-content:center;
        -ms-justify-content:center;
        -o-justify-content:center;
        justify-content:center;
        -webkit-align-items:center;
        -moz-align-items:center;
        -ms-align-items:center;
        -o-align-items:center;
        align-items:center;
        -webkit-flex-direction:column;
        -moz-flex-direction:column;
        -ms-flex-direction:column;
        -o-flex-direction:column;
        flex-direction:column;
    }
    picture {            
        width:80%;
    }
    #temp {
        background-color:red;
    }
</style>

thanks!
```

Comment: Thanks for help sir.I just tried it,but i am afraid it is no use.

Comment: sir, if you afraid to see the code , you can try this for only ie -

Comment: -ms-justify-content:center;

Comment: I just tried,but it is no use again.I think may be the problem is someone said that the picture element in IE11 is unsupported

Comment: @MelonNG As I understand it, IE11's lack of support just means that it ignores `picture` and `source` elements. As long as you have an `img` with a valid `src` attribute as a child of the `picture`, it should fall back to that as if the other markup wasn't there.

Comment: @Brombardier now I have given up support the html5 in IE, just support all ie browser in a version and support Firefox/Chrome in another version website page.